# css responsive blend-mode

Tags: css, responsive

У меня есть два div,в первом находится фотография с background-color:blue;,во втором находится стиль mix-blend-mode: multiply;Bторому div задано position relative и перекрывает 20% фотографии.

Как сделать так чтобы второй DIV был постоянно responsive?Потому что когда меняешь размер экрана 2 Div теряет свою форму и становится шире чем фотография.

Answer (score 0):

Впервые от вас узнал про mix-blend-mode )
Методом тыка попробовал что-то сделать, вышло так:

[ДЕМО](https://liveweave.com/4AhQry)

```
<div class="bu-1"></div>

<div class="bu-2"><img class="mix" src="..."></div>
```

CSS:

Основную картинку, которая должна быть слева в синем диве, поместил как задний фон, через background-image:

```
.bu-1 {background-color:  #045acf;
       width: 100%;
       height: 200px;
       position: absolute;
       text-align: center;
       background-image: url('ссылка.png');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: 100% 200px;
       }
```

Чтобы картинка в случае чего, не повторялась и была одна - `background-repeat: no-repeat;`, а чтобы приняла ширину и высоту дива - `background-size: 100% 200px;`, чтобы в случае чего, располагалась всегда по центру - `text-align: center;`, хотя тут не обязательно.

А второй див через `float: right` отправляется направо:

```
.bu-2 {width:  20%;
       height: 200px;
       float: right;
       text-align: center;
       position: relative;
       border: 2px solid red;
       }
```

И задается ширина 20%, чтобы всегда прикрывала только 20% основного див-а.
Ну и картинка внутри 20-процентного дива:

```
.mix {mix-blend-mode: multiply;
      width: 100%;}
```